# How to bind tmux window selection to f1-f12 keys?

Tags: tmux

At the moment I move between tmux windows using C-B N where N is the number of the window I want. Is there a way to map the f keys so that I can just press f1 to activate the 1st window, f2 to activate the 2nd window, etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `tmux` allows a command to be bound to most keys, with or without a prefix key. […] In addition, the following special key names are accepted: Up, […] `F1` to `F12`, […].

<sup>(source: [`man 1 tmux`](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#KEY_BINDINGS))</sup>

Run this in a shell inside `tmux`:

```
for n in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12; do
   tmux bind-key -T root "F$n" select-window -t "$n"
done
```

To make the bindings permanent, edit your `.tmux.conf` and add 12 lines in a form:

```
bind-key -T root F1 select-window -t 1
# up to
bind-key -T root F12 select-window -t 12
```

---

Notes:

- `tmux` enumerates windows from `0` but there is no <kbd>F0</kbd> key. Your requirement does not cover the 0th window.
- Sequences generated by <kbd>F1</kbd>..<kbd>F12</kbd> depend on few things, mostly on the terminal emulator and its settings. I can tell `tmux` recognizes `^[OP`, `^[OQ`, `^[OR`, `^[OS`, but then `^[[15~` instead of `^[OT` and so on; so you need to adjust your terminal settings. E.g. while connected to Debian via PuTTY from Windows, I need to choose *Xterm R6* in PuTTY *Settings* → *Terminal* → *Keyboard* → *The Function keys and keypad*. I notice *VT400* and *VT100+* work partially. I don't know if you can do the adjustment the other way around (i.e. adjust `tmux` to your terminal).
- Some programs use function keys for their own purposes and you may want `tmux` to let them. This example snippet for `.tmux.conf` makes <kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>F2</kbd> work in `mc` and `vim`:

  ```
  # Using function keys to select windows, except in mc or vim
  tmux_commands_with_function_keys="mc vim"
  bind-key -T root F1 \
     if-shell 'echo "#{tmux_commands_with_function_keys}" | grep -q "#{pane_current_command}"' \
        'send F1' 'select-window -t 1'
  bind-key -T root F2 \
     if-shell 'echo "#{tmux_commands_with_function_keys}" | grep -q "#{pane_current_command}"' \
        'send F2' 'select-window -t 2'
  ```