# Bypass tmux key bindings temporarily and send a key literally

Tags: tmux

I have bindings for some of my F-keys in the `root` key table, i.e. without a need to use the prefix key to use them.

Is it possible to temporarily, out of the box or by configuring a binding, bypass all bindings for the next key pressed, so an F-key could be sent even if there's a binding for it?

Screen has `mapdefault` for that.

I'm aware that bindings can be [conditionally configured/enabled](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/594486/how-to-bind-tmux-window-selection-to-f1-f12-keys), which is pretty neat, but doesn't quite make up for a general solution.

Comment: Define F<n> with prefix where it sends just F<n>?

Comment: Thanks, I guess that would work. A general solution with fewer lines of configuration would be even better, though.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have tmux 3.1 available on all systems I want to share my tmux config with. But I guess until then, I could go without `-k`, even if that's a bit more cumbersome... So I would accept this, if you want to make it an answer.